# Size of pdf generated with reportLab

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I have a problem with the generation of my pdf.

When I generate a pdf and after few minute when I restart the same script to generate the same pdf I don't have the same size between my first pdf and the second...

this is my code :

```
c = reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas("test.pdf")
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

The first pdf have : `1519` byte

And the second have `1531` byte

Whenever I restart the same script and whenever I have differents value.
Why? How can I resolve it?

Comment: The difference is due to the random generated `ID` inside the `trailer` section of the generated PDF file.

Comment: @acw1668, is there a solution to resolve it?

Comment: @acw1668, Can I get the `ID` of a pdf ? And can I set a specific `ID` before save the pdf?

Comment: @acw1668, It's okay, I found I add `reportlab.rl_config.invariant = 1`, Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem of the PDF changing size, but its contents are changing:

```
$ python make_pdf.py && md5sum test.pdf
9a1dbc5621622526b4411fb5f818246e  test.pdf
$ python make_pdf.py && md5sum test.pdf
b4c3ef4661c2a0f7d5c458757ac8a891  test.pdf
$
```

Following the hint from your comment, setting the [`invariant` option](https://github.com/Distrotech/reportlab/blob/ReportLab_3_3_0/src/reportlab/rl_settings.py#L69) solves that.

```
import reportlab.pdfgen.canvas
import reportlab.rl_config

reportlab.rl_config.invariant = 1
c = reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas("test.pdf")
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Now the contents don't change, because the PDF doesn't get a generated id, and the timestamp is set to 0:00 01 Jan 2000 UTC.

```
$ python make_pdf.py && md5sum test.pdf
4a0ecf533e69fc2a91cda0a055cbec58  test.pdf
$ python make_pdf.py && md5sum test.pdf
4a0ecf533e69fc2a91cda0a055cbec58  test.pdf
$
```